# Display Images from on server file system using Angular6 and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I can successfully upload images to a Server but there is no tutorial of **how to display images present in Server using Angular6 and NodeJS**. Need some help guys.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: **I got Solution after a lot of trail and errors**, Retrieving file stored in a D Drive in Server

Added this code in NodeJS Index page
NodeJS: `app.use(express.static('D:/school'));`

Now I can get Images using `http://localhost:3000/ImageName`

Just add this URL in angular img src tag

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/ImageName">
```

Comment: How do you store images in localstorage? base64?

Comment: I have updated my code @rjv , but whats that base64, I have no idea

Comment: `localStorage` is an entirely different animal, your question must say `images from server` https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: Omg ya sorry let me update my Question. I meant it as D drive and not that local storage

Comment: Ok then can u help me of getting images from server???

Comment: I have edited the question, you can leave it as is

Comment: No, Nodejs it'not angular, it's backend, you could use javascript or typescript or others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nodejs you could then have it serve up your images as static content: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

your code just load the image as:

```
$scope.img= "/images-folder/img.png"

<img id="imgid" ng-src="{{img}}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but according to the Docs they gave http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg , but what to do if I have them saved inside some D drive and not in project folder

Comment: I could not tell you, it could work the same but I'm not sure, I'm sorry.

Comment: No, Nodejs it'not angular, it's backend, you could use javascript or typescript or others.